# LinkedEntityid is the user incorrectly coming in ContentDocumentLink trigger

Tags: contentdocumentlink

I am creating a trigger on ContentDocumentLink and I am attaching a file via upload file option in related list to a record. In trigger(after insert), the linkEntityId is generated as user id but I want to track the record id to which it attached to. How can I achieve this.

```
private void populateDocumentCount(List<ContentDocumentLink> newdocuments){    
    List<id> documentlinkids = new List<Id>();
    for(ContentDocumentLink cdLink:newdocuments){
        documentlinkids.add(cdLink.LinkedEntityid);
    }    
    List<ContentDocumentLink> docList = [select id, LinkedEntityid from ContentDocumentLink where LinkedEntityid IN: documentlinkids];
}
```

In the above code "documentlinkids" contains the id of the user rather record id.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trigger for contentdocumentLink fired twice one for User currently uploading the document and one for the record against which document being uploaded. At the second time when the trigger is fired I get the data which I wanted i.e ContentdocumentLink against the record to which file being loaded.

Comment: How are you differentiating between these two firings?

Comment: @SarojBera Use Key Prefix to distinguish between the call. the user id and record id have different keyprefix.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to use **ContentDocumentId** instead of **LinkedEntityId**
As *LinkedEntityId* contains

> ID of the linked object. Can include Chatter users, groups, records
>   (any that support Chatter feed tracking including custom objects), and
>   Salesforce CRM Content libraries.

and ContentDocumentId contains

> ID of the document.

Comment: I have also tried with ContentDocumentId but it returns the same thing.  the interesting thing is, in the trigger the query returns one record of contentDocumentLink but in developer console it returns two record one for user and one for record against it's uploaded to.